# Apple Developer Account expired and Ad Hoc distributed app not working

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I created an iOS app for a small company approximately one year ago. It is a small app to help the employees, so the easiest method of distribution seemed to be ad hoc. I simply had the .ipa file available for download and had the users trust my developer account.

I accidentally forgot to renew my apple developer account, and now the app will not open on anyone's phone.

I'm trying to figure out the best method to solve this issue. If I renew my developer account, would I have to redistribute the app to everyone?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1):

You will have to reactive your develop account for sure, but it all depends on if you have to get a new signing cert which you probably do. That will require redistribution of the app.